# Can't stub with mocha in ruby on rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-mocha

I'm fairly new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails and having trouble stubbing out a method via `mocha` in an existing codebase.

I've simplified the code down to a MWE where this breaks.

Here is `test_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "rails/test_help"


class ActiveSupport::TestCase

end


class Minitest::Test
  def before_setup

  end
end
```

And here is the test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'mocha/minitest'

class MyTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  describe "some test" do
    it "should stub" do
      My::Class.stubs(:bar).returns("foo")
      puts My::Class.bar
    end
  end

end
```

This results in the following error when I run the test:

`Mocha::NotInitializedError: Mocha methods cannot be used outside the context of a test`

However, when I redefine my `test_helper.rb` as follows:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "rails/test_help"


class ActiveSupport::TestCase

end


# class Minitest::Test
#   def before_setup
#
#   end
# end
```

The test passes (and "foo" is printed as expected).

Why does the `class Minitest::Test...end` in `test_helper.rb` cause the first error? I can't remove that code from the actual codebase, so how can I modify it to work with `mocha`?

Ruby version: 2.4.1

Rails version: 4.2.8

Mocha version: 1.5.0

Comment: How about turning those methods into a module and including it to Minitest::Test?

Comment: @maxpleaner which methods do you mean? Could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: Change `class Minitest::Test` to `module MiniTestPatch` and then call `Minitest::Test.include MiniTestPatch` outside the definition. Just worth a shot, I don't know if it will work.

Comment: Actually, you should use `prepend` instead of `include`, and possibly you should be calling `super` in the patched method

Comment: Adding a call to `super` in `before_setup` did the trick - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a call to `super` in the patched method `before_setup` in `test_helper.rb` works:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "rails/test_help"


class ActiveSupport::TestCase

end


class Minitest::Test
  def before_setup
      # do something
      super
  end
end
```

This call to `super` allows the `before_setup` of `Mocha::Integration::MiniTest` to be called, which is necessary for proper initialization.